# jQuery. Placeholder remove on focus and back on blur

Tags: jquery

The site has input fields. No matter what. No matter how many. How to make it so that when the focus in each field placeholder is completely removed, and the loss of focus - placeholder back in its place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go:

```js
$(function(){
 $('input').on('focus blur', function(){
     if($(this).attr('placeholder')){
         $(this).attr('placeholder', '');
        } else {
         $(this).attr('placeholder', 'Placeholder');
        };
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Placeholder">
```

**But the next time please provide some code of what you tried.**

Answer (score 0):

It's browser default behaviour(unless it's Old IE 9,8) to `remove placeholder text` on `focus` and put it back on `blur` if the field is `empty`. What do you want to achieve?

For unsupported browsers, use plugin https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder. It's support passwords fields as well.